# Does a new instance of an object need to be created every time I add it to a Queue or Stack? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, object, pointers, queue

I am having trouble adding a series of char* objects to a Queue (CHCircularBufferQueue). The Queue takes an object as input (as far as I understand), so i created a simple object inherited from NSObject called tokenObject that simply contains a char* tokenName. Everytime I add a new tokenObject to the Queue, I allocate a new tokenObject and then pass that new one into the Queue the next time I add to Queue. However, when I set tokenObject.tokenName to a new char* string, it overrides ALL the tokenObjects in the Queue, so when I print the whole Queue, I get a series of the same strings instead of unique strings. What am I doing incorrectly?

This is in objective-c

Below is the code from main.m & tokenObject.h
main.m:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CHCircularBufferQueue *tokenQueue = [[CHCircularBufferQueue alloc] init];
    tokenObject *myTokenObject = [[tokenObject alloc] init];


TK currentToken;
initScanner();
scanToken();
[myTokenObject setTokenName:getToken() ];
currentToken = getTkrep();

int x=0;

while (x<5/*currentToken != TK_EOF*/) {


        //printf("line number: %d, token value: %d, token string: %s\n", getLinenumber(), getTkrep(), getToken()); /* replace line with "add to queue" */
    scanToken();
    myTokenObject.tokenName = getToken();
    [tokenQueue addObject:myTokenObject];
    myTokenObject = [[tokenObject alloc] init];
    currentToken = getTkrep();


    x = x+1;
}

while(x != 1){
    printf("%s", [[tokenQueue firstObject] tokenName]);
    [tokenQueue removeFirstObject];
    x = x-1;

    printf("%i", x);
}
return 0;
```

}

tokenObject.h:

```
@interface tokenObject : NSObject{

    char *tokenName;
}
@property (assign) char* tokenName;
```

@end

Comment: You don't need to create a new object every time you add something, but for your case you need distinct objects because there's only one tokenName pointer in your custom object.  (Why not just add NSString objects??)

Comment: What exactly goes `getToken` do?  Does it return a newly-allocated string that you are responsible for freeing, or is it something that it might keep internally and modify?  That said, I would also second Licks's question as to why you're not using `NSString`.

Comment: I'm about to try implementing NSString instead of subclassing myself, but how exactly would I implement that? getToken() returns a char* and was provided by my professor so I cannot modify that portion of the code. what is the setter function for NSString?

Comment: How about you go take a look at the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation?  Also, if this is homework, you might want to tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample goes against cocoa best practices in a few ways. For one thing, you typically kick off your functionality in your application's delegate, not in main.m.

However in answer to your question, try using an NSString * instead of a char *. Does your custom TokenObject do anything other than posses a string? If so, avoid subclassing altogether and just allocate/assign NSStrings directly, and add those to your queue. You should find the results more to your expectation.

Comment: I think he is making a command-line application, not one with a user interface (and therefore, one that does not need an application delegate).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try that out right now. On the topic of cocoa practices, where exactly do I kickoff my code? I am creating a command-line parsing tool for an objective-c class. Would that apply to my project? (I'm learning objective c for the first time, so excuse me if my questions seem stupid)

Comment: No problem, the question isn't stupid, we all start somewhere. If you are making a command line tool, then main.m is actually fine.

Comment: So I've switched the tokenObject.tokenName data type to:
'NSString * tokenName'

but I still see the same string repeatedly in the output

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each member of your queue should hold a unique object. Otherwise you are loading your queue with the same object over and over again. So every time you do `myTokenObject.tokenName = getToken();` you overwrite all the tokens in the entire queue. If you create a unique object for each position in the queue, each object will hold a unique token.

Comment: If you look at his code, he's allocating a new object for each token.  As such, he's not modifying all the tokens in the queue.  It seems more likely that the `getToken` method is returning an address to some buffer that it modifies for each token.